# Using jQuery to Swap Out Body Background Image on click and randomize on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a body background image that is being "placed" by a plugin called ezBigResize that basically allows the image to scale with the browser window.

The designer wants to image though to be able to be swapped out by a series of thumbnails on the page, along with that image being randomized on page load from that series of images.

Initially before those two additions, I just had it setup like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {$("body").ezBgResize({img : "/lib/img/bkgr/mainBG.jpg"});});
```

Then this is the code now (in a jQuery Tools scrollable)

```
<div id="bkgrSelector">
    <div class="scrollNav">
        <a class="prev browse left"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollable">   
        <div class="items">
            <img src="/lib/img/bkgr/selections/main-bg.jpg" width="77" height="44" />
            <img src="/lib/img/bkgr/selections/main-bg02.jpg" width="77" height="44" />
            <img src="/lib/img/bkgr/selections/main-bg03.jpg" width="77" height="44" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollNav">
        <a class="next browse right"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm a little over my head though to allow these to both randomize on page load and to swap out the image via the value in the href.

I tried something like this, but it didn't work and is obviously inclomplete. Plus, it doesn't address the randomization at all.

```
$('#bkgrSelector .items img[href]').click(function()
{
            $("body").css("background-image", "url()");
        });
```

Any ideas, help, etc. would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are those `<img>` pointing at the full-sized image file? I absolutely LOATHE sites that use full-size images and shrink them to thumbnail size. The load times are attrocious.

If they're actually thumbnail-sized images, you won't be able to use that url directly as your background url, as you'd just be stretching a small thumbnail-sized image to cover the window and get a hideous pixelized mess.

If the page is being dynamically generated, you'd want to create a JS array that contains the URLs of the full-sized image urls, so that when a thumbnail is clicked, you can get the fullsize url from that array. Or at least have a standardized naming convention so a simple string manipulation lets you turn the thumbnail url into a fullsize image url.

Once you've got that array, it's a simple matter to randomize a choice from it:

```
var imgs = ['/url/for/img1.jpg', '/url/for/img2.jpg', etc....];

$(document).ready(function() {
   randomUrl = imgs[Math.round(Math.random() * (imgs.length - 1)) + 1];
   $("body").css("background-image", 'url(' + randomURL + ')');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Marc, I will be generating separate thumbs for the small images. Was just trying to keep things simple (as possible) for my question.

I've got it up and running based on your solution.